# Postgresql mathematical functions (factorial)

Tags: postgresql

I have been learning postgresql, and for some reason when i do factorial operations, my terminal says: "syntax error at or near ';'".

Every other basic mathematical operations like add; sub; multiply; divide; modulo; power works, but not factorial operator.

I will link the screenshot of my terminal.

Please somebody help with this problem.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F94UN.jpg)

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text, do not link a painting of them.

Comment: What version are you on? `!` might have been already removed in it. Use the function `factorial()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Postgres 14 [removed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/) the `!` operator for factorial:

> Remove factorial operators `!` and `!!`, as well as function `numeric_fac()`
> The `factorial()` function is still supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [factorial()](https://pgpedia.info/f/factorial.html) function to get the factorial you want. Ex:

```
SELECT factorial(5);
```